# Errors still print to the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, apt

I'm writing a bash script here to install docker and send all outputs to the logs.txt file. But i still get errors such as the one below displayed on the terminal, what I'm i doing wrong here to get these errors?

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

```
    if [[ `command -v apt-get` ]]; then
    echo -e "\n${GREEN}[${WHITE}+${GREENS}]${GREENS} Getting requirements....."
        sleep 1;
        sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release >> logs.txt
    echo -e "\n${GREEN}[${WHITE}+${GREENS}]${GREENS} Adding Docker’s official GPG key........"
        sleep 1;
        curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
    echo -e "\n${GREEN}[${WHITE}+${GREENS}]${GREENS} Installing Docker......."
        sleep 1;
        sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io >> logs.txt
    echo -e "\n${GREEN}[${WHITE}+${GREENS}]${GREENS} Docker version........"
        sleep 1;
        docker --version | head -n1
```

Comment: You're sending standard output to the log file, not standard error.

Comment: You can send error output to the file as well by appending `2>&1` to each command.

Comment: @Barmar same error prints when i use "> logs.txt 2>&1"

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so you can see which command is doing this.

Comment: If `2>&1` doesn't redirect the errors, it must be writing them directly to `/dev/tty` for some reason.

Comment: That error is related to apt-get.  You can only run one at a time, and each execution tries to obtain the lock, hence the error you see.  Add a `2>> logs.txt` to both apt-get lines to capture the errors.